# Simple Extending Base Layout in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a **base.twig** in the path *project/views/base.twig*. I have another file **new.twig** that I wish to extend **base.twig** in *project/views/new.twig*. I use:

base.twig:

```
{% block head %}
    <header>
        <a href="/new"> New </a>
        <a href="/view"> View </a>
        <a href="/edit"> Edit </a>
    </header>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{% block foot %}
{% endblock %}
```

new.twig:

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
   <form> ...something here... </form>
{% endblock %}
```

However, this isn't working (the error output is unclear/responding with a status 500). I've read other Q&A's on this, but they seem to be more complicated than my issue, and I don't quite understand what exactly is wrong.  What am I doing incorrectly?

**SOLUTION**

Silly, but I didn't think this mattered (so did not include it in the code above); it turns out I had some `<link>` and `<script></script>` tags outside of the blocks in **new.twig**. This won't work unless you define a block for them in **base.twig**.

Answer (score 0):

The twig files seem okay, so my guess is that your Twig_Environment isn't correctly set to load from `project/views/`.
Since you're using symfony2, that shouldn't be the case...

If that's not the case, you probably need to dig for the exception stack trace.